# Loop through Excel sheets in Python

Tags: excel, pandas, glob

I am trying to extract all data from one excel file (data is spread into different sheets from the same file) into one new excel file

```
import pandas as pd
import glob as glob

appended_data = []
f_list = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test\
               *.xlsx') 
for f in f_list: 
    data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name= ('May', 'April'))
    appended_data.append(data)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
appended_data.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test\appended.xlsx')
```

the problem is in the sheet_name if i try the code below :

```
data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name= [0,1,2,3])
```

i get a `Value Error : No objects to concatenate`

the code only works when i type the name of one sheet  :

```
data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name="April")
```

But it doesn't work when i try the name of two sheets or more :

```
data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name= ('May', 'April'))
```

How to tell the code to loop through all the sheets?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read all sheets by providing sheet_name=None

```
dict_of_frames = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
```

full example:

```
all_sheets = []
for f in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test\*.xlsx'):
        all_sheets.extend(pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None).values())
data = pd.concat(all_sheets)
data.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test\appended.xlsx')
```

Comment: same problem : No objects to concatenate

Comment: I think this error is coming from the `pd.concat(appended_data)` line. Can you validate that the `appended_data` list is not empty

Answer (score 1):

Get all sheet names using pd.ExcelFile class

```
sheet_names = pd.ExcelFile(f).sheet_names
```

and iterate them via a generator

```
appended_data = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=s) for s in sheet_names))
```

Update with the context:

```
appended_data = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None) for f in f_list))
```

Comment: it says that the sheet_name is not defined

Comment: Of course the sheet_names are specific for every file if you iterate files.
Thus, you should (for example) save `appended_data` to a list, and then pd.concat that list again. Anyway the solution with sheet_names=None above is much simpler and elegant.